# Is it possible to expose the api endpoints from a C# sdk in order to use Javascript?

Tags: javascript, canon-sdk

I want to expose the canon camera SDK to use it with Javascript. I don't know C# (I know someone will say to just learn it...). But really just wondering if this is even possible? The SDK only allows C, C++, C#, Objective-C, and Swift. So I guess any of those would work.

I figured the StackOverflow gods would have a definite answer.

Comment: About what kind of SDK you are talking? Your named languages are "back-end" languages, while JS is front end. If there is no server listening for API calls, then you can't do anything with JS.

Comment: Well you can use the api from js, but there is no sdk it seems, so you will have to make requests yourself to the camera endpoints, look at this https://github.com/camerahacks/canon-ccapi-node/

Comment: @Justinas you know that javascript is already backend language too?

Comment: @Seti https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-node-js-and-javascript/

Comment: Still - the language itself is used as backend language - node allows that. Programming in nodejs is a bit different than in javascript (mostly because if of small misinterpretation as thinking ppl that use js in node.js environment are node.js programmers - they are not - they are merely javascript programmers using node.js environment to run theirs programs - but still - language is language, origin is not important as far as current usage is - and JavaScript as a language is used also for writing backends (with node.js env, but the language is the same)

Answer (score 0):

Even though I wasn't able to use the SDK, I did find exactly what I wanted in the comment posted by @Lk77

I wanted to be able to make a UI for camera controls remotely and I thought that was only possible using the cannon sdk but actually, cannon provides an exposed interface to use when you enable the CCAPI on the camera itself. And that repo had a pretty good example. Thanks for all the help everyone.